# protocol flow tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

can somebody please help with tikz suggestion to create the attached protocol diagram?
Many thanks

[image]

Comment: Hmm, do you really need TikZ for this?

Comment: not really, can you point me to something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does it for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c c c}
\text{\textsf{Prover}} & & \text{\textsf{Verifier}} \\
(x = \log_g h) & & \\
u\in_R \mathbb{Z}_n & & \\
a \gets g^u & \xrightarrow{\hspace{1em}a\hspace{1em}} & \\
& & c\in_R \{0,1\} \\
& \xleftarrow{\hspace{1em}c\hspace{1em}} & \\
r\gets_n\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{l l}
u, & \text{if}\ c=0 \\
u + x, & \text{if}\ c=1 
\end{array}
\end{cases} & \xleftarrow{\hspace{1em}r\hspace{1em}} & g^r \stackrel{?}{=}
\begin{cases}
\begin{array}{l l}
a, & \text{if}\ c=0 \\
ah, & \text{if}\ c=1
\end{array}
\end{cases}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Preview:

[image]

---

**UPDATE:** I have missed braces around `{0,1}`. I have fixed the LaTeX above and not updated the preview.